# I have a project Converted from VB6 to VB.Net that uses .NET 4.5.2 with a BaseControlArray Issue

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

Ok so, I had a Line Control on a form on the VB6 Version however the conversion made a file on it separately. The Compiled Output works but it comes with a Warning that I want to remove for 4.6+ support for if Miscorsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility was to be removed that I would be fine without referencing it.

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks

<ProvideProperty("Index", GetType(LineShape))> Friend Class LineShapeArray
    Inherits BaseControlArray
    Implements IExtenderProvider

    Public Event [Click] As EventHandler

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal Container As IContainer)
        MyBase.New(Container)
    End Sub

    Public Function CanExtend(ByVal Target As Object) As Boolean Implements IExtenderProvider.CanExtend
        If TypeOf Target Is LineShape Then
            Return BaseCanExtend(Target)
        End If
        Return 0
    End Function

    Public Function GetIndex(ByVal o As LineShape) As Short
        Return BaseGetIndex(o)
    End Function

    Public Sub SetIndex(ByVal o As LineShape, ByVal Index As Short)
        BaseSetIndex(o, Index)
    End Sub

    Public Function ShouldSerializeIndex(ByVal o As LineShape) As Boolean
        Return BaseShouldSerializeIndex(o)
    End Function

    Public Sub ResetIndex(ByVal o As LineShape)
        BaseResetIndex(o)
    End Sub

    Public Shadows Sub Load(ByVal Index As Short)
        MyBase.Load(Index)
        CType(Item(0).Parent, ShapeContainer).Shapes.Add(Item(Index))
    End Sub

    Public Shadows Sub Unload(ByVal Index As Short)
        CType(Item(0).Parent, ShapeContainer).Shapes.Remove(Item(Index))
        MyBase.Unload(Index)
    End Sub

    Public Default ReadOnly Property Item(ByVal Index As Short) As LineShape
        Get
            Item = CType(BaseGetItem(Index), LineShape)
        End Get
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub HookUpControlEvents(ByVal o As Object)
        Dim ctl As LineShape
        ctl = CType(o, LineShape)
        If Not IsNothing(ClickEvent) Then
            AddHandler ctl.Click, ClickEvent
        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Function GetControlInstanceType() As System.Type
        Return GetType(LineShape)
    End Function
End Class
```

And the Warning:

```
warning BC40000: 'BaseControlArray' is obsolete: 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.* classes are obsolete and supported within 32 bit processes only. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=160862'.
```

And the link in the Warning not actually being Helpful at all to fixing this Warning.

I ended up doing this in the Form's paint event that uses the lines after the Answer to the question below that I marked:

```
    Private Sub Form2_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Gray, 0, 151, Me.Width, 151)
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.White, 0, 152, Me.Width, 152)
    End Sub
```

The `y1` and `y2` values in `DrawLine` can be replaced to the form height that is wanted. Same for the `Pens` Color.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's also meaningless to say *it comes with a Warning* without showing us the code and exactly what *warning* it produces.

Comment: Edited it now with the entire file's data.

Comment: Whats the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three issues: control arrays, line control, use of Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.

1. Use [FloatingKiwi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38821261/15639) to avoid control arrays.
2. Replace Line control with .Net line drawing methods [as explained here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yscxd11(v=vs.90).aspx). I recommend you do not use the Power Pack Line Control, since the Power Packs are no longer being updated.
3. It's a good idea to stop using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility just in case it is retired, though personally I would consider getting the whole project working first (with Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility if necessary), then seek to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct equivalent you can use.

[See here for someone who had the same issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b2d13c9a-e320-4f36-981e-e4c1999d7694/vbnet-equivalent-of-vb6-code-which-are-obsolete?forum=vbinterop)

[And resolved it using this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289500(VS.71).aspx)